# Incorrect timezone offset

Tags: c#, timezone

I am trying to make sense of a timezone issue. I am located in Norway, which is gmt+1 and I am trying to convert a UTC time to local time. From my understanding, this means that local time should be utc + 1 hour. So 12:00 utc should become 13:00 local. For some reason I keep getting + 2 hours.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nb-NO");
var zone = System.TimeZoneInfo.Local;                           // Zone = {(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Oslo, Roma, Wien}
DateTime time = DateTime.Parse("2019-04-01T00:00:00+00:00");    // time = {01.04.2019 02:00:00} Why is this not 01:00:00 when timzone = utc+1?
var offset = zone.GetUtcOffset(time);                           // Offset = {02:00:00}

DateTime timeWithoutUtc = DateTime.Parse("2019-04-01T00:00:00");
var t2 = timeWithoutUtc.ToLocalTime();                          // {01.04.2019 02:00:00}

DateTimeOffset timeOffsetWithUtc = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2019-04-01T00:00:00+00:00");
var t3 = timeOffsetWithUtc.ToLocalTime();                       // {01.04.2019 02:00:00 +02:00}
```

I am sure this is something really basic, but I cant seem to understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: You have daylights savings in Norway, don’t you? So by 1 April it’s kicked in and 2 hours from UTC is correct?

Comment: Thank you! Daylight saving has not started, but by 1 April it has. I was going insane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not consider that daylight saving starts when the date in the example is. Thanks to sellotape for pointing it out.